# Is there a PCA quality metric to compare data subsets?

Tags: pca

I would like to see if on a subset of the data (selected by a range of a particular feature) 2-component PCA does particularly well.

Is there a quality metric - apart from explained variance - which is independent of data size *and insensitive to statistical effects of small sample fits*?